# How to clone a NotesDocument java object

Tags: java, xpages, clone

I have the following java code and when I try to access the MiscDoc object later it seem to be null.  I could not find a .clone() method on NotesDocument.

the if statement is only accessed once

```
Document MiscDoc = null;
wdoc = dcAll.getFirstDocument();
while (wdoc != null){       
            if(...){
                MiscDoc = wdoc;
            }
            Document tmpdoc = dcAll.getNextDocument();
            wdoc.recycle();
            wdoc = tmpdoc;
}
```

how can I resolve this

Answer (score 2):

As you recycle **every** document in while loop your MiscDoc is also recycled and null after loop.

Just don't recycle this certain document and it will be available after while loop.

Easiest way is to add `break;` if you are just looking for the first document that matches if(...) condition:

```
while (wdoc != null) {       
    if(...){
        MiscDoc = wdoc;
        break;
    }
```